# Zip all the files within the folder in jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have some files in Jenkins work space. I want all the files to be zipped and zip should now include the root folder and should include only the contents within the folder.

I have already tried using file operation plugin which actually zips the files. But problem using this plugin is that all the files are inside an root folder. What i need is as soon as i unzip i should only get the files and not the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the [manven assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html).

You can then configure it [to  include file without taking its path folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46092911/6309), using:

- `<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>`-
- `fileSets`

Comment: i dont see this plugin available in jenkins

Comment: @ashish I meant as part of a Maven Jenkins plugin, through a pom.xml

Comment: could you provide me detailed steps as i am new to this

Comment: @ashish First, what plugin where you using yourself? Do you have a link?

Comment: i was using file operation plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it using terminal 
got to the root directory or the directory that have all the files you want then :

`tar chvfz workspace.tar.gz *`
will zip all the files in the workspace in workspace.tar.gz
if you wanna zip specific files u can list them instead of using `*`